# Expo build android failed React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I am not able to generate the internal apk since the expo SDK 47 update occurred, I get an error installing dependencies on some occasions and in Run gradlew.

[image]

I show the error in installation of dependencies:

[image]

```
Running "npm install" in the root dir of your repository 2[stderr] npm ERR!3[stderr] code ERESOLVE4[stderr] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve5[stderr] npm ERR! 6[stderr] npm ERR! While resolving: react-navigation-tabs@2.11.27[stderr] npm ERR! Found: react-native-gesture-handler@2.8.08[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler9[stderr] npm ERR!   react-native-gesture-handler@"~2.8.0" from the root project10[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@">= 1.0.0" from @react-navigation/stack@6.3.711[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack12[stderr] npm ERR!     @react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.2" from the root project13[stderr] npm ERR!   1 more (react-native-tab-view)14[stderr] npm ERR! 15[stderr] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:16[stderr] npm ERR! peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.0" from react-navigation-tabs@2.11.217[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-tabs18[stderr] npm ERR!   react-navigation-tabs@"^2.11.2" from the root project19[stderr] npm ERR! 20[stderr] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-gesture-handler@1.10.321[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler22[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.0" from react-navigation-tabs@2.11.223[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-tabs24[stderr] npm ERR!     react-navigation-tabs@"^2.11.2" from the root project25[stderr] npm ERR! 26[stderr] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry27[stderr] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps28[stderr] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.29[stderr] npm ERR! 30[stderr] npm ERR! See /home/expo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.31[stderr] 32[stderr] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:33[stderr] npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2022-12-09T04_28_24_722Z-debug-0.log34npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

I show the error in "Run gradlew":

[image]

delete the package-lock.json file, delete the node_modules folder, npm cache clean --force, npm cache verify and install npm install again

Comment: This happened to me as well. It ended up being that one of my node modules in package.json was inadvertently deleted during the SDK update. Check your modules, make sure the app runs correctly on emulator/device and check your app.json for any missing objects.